# p:commandButton not rendering inside a p:galleria in .xhtml

Tags: primefaces

Im trying to make a delete button in a <p:galleria> element using primefaces, but when i put the <p:commandButton> inside the element it doesnt render, but i can find it in the inspect element. If i use a <h:commandButton> it render normally.

code:

```
<p:galleria value="#{anexoEventoBean.anexosEvidencias}" var="evidencia" showCaption="true" autoPlay="false" rendered="#{anexoEventoBean.existeAnexosEvento}" id="galeriaAnexos">
     <p:commandButton id="excluirEvidenciaButton" icon="far fa-trash-alt" actionListener="#{anexoEventoBean.excluirEvidencia()}" immediate="true"> 
        <p:graphicImage value="#{evidencia.arquivo.caminhoArquivo}" id="imagemEvidencia" height="450" width="580" cache="false" title="#{evidencia.descricao}"/>
        <f:param id="idEvidencia" name="idEvidencia" value="#{evidencia.id}"/>
    </p:commandButton>  
</p:galleria>
```

Comment: _" it doesnt render, but i can find it in the inspect element"_  Then check with a browser developer tool what the issue is. If it is 'technically' rendered from a `p:commandButton` to client side html, that all works

Comment: It doesnt show any error or warnings in the browser developer tool

Comment: I'm not talking about errors or warnings, specifically... CSS that makes it hidden could be a cause too...

Comment: Move out the graphicImage component from the inside of the commandButton